# Redirect Find Command output to a file

Tags: find

```
#!  /bin/ksh
inputfile="/lawson/usr/u105513/LibList1.csv"

outfile="2.txt"


while read Libname
do
   echo $Libname
   find /ptchdev5/apps/patch10/ -name $Libname -print > $outfile
done < $inputfile

exit 0
```

I am trying to redirect the ouput of find command to a file

I tried #!  /bin/sh
find /ptchdev5/apps/patch10/ -type f -name $Libname -print > $outfile

but nothing works, the output file comes out as blank only

Comment: #!  /bin/ksh
    inputfile="/lawson/usr/u105513/LibList1.csv"

    outfile="2.txt"
    while read Libname
    do
       echo $Libname
       find /ptchdev5/apps/patch10/ -name ${Libname} -print > $outfile
    done < $inputfile
    
This worked for me

Comment: find /ptchdev5/apps/patch10/ -name ${Libname} -print > $outfile